# Discord bot can't connected to voice channel (python)

Tags: python, discord, bots, voice

Hy
I want to make a discord bot in python, that can connected to voice channel. My code:

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
  channel = ctx.author.voice
  if str(channel) == 'None':
    await ctx.channel.send(':x: You have to be in a voice channel to use this command. :x:')
  else:
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```

This error is displayed

```
Ignoring exception in command join:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 25, in join
    await channel.connect()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1150, in connect
    voice = cls(client, self)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/voice_client.py", line 199, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice")
RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice
```

If anyone has an idea, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install the PyNaCl library, which you can grab using pip: https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/

Comment: Thanks. When I download the file, how can I use this in the code?

Comment: When I use the 'pip install' command, this error is displayed:

pip install C:\ProgramData\Discord\PyNaCl-1.4.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Requirement 'C:ProgramDataDiscordPyNaCl-1.4.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'C:ProgramDataDiscordPyNaCl==1.4.0'
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/virtualenvs/python3/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: See https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/ for info on how to use pip. Ensure pip is runnable, and then run the command `pip install pynacl` It will automatically grab the latest source and install.